# Products color should show through color variations in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I have added two variations at product page in woocommerce.

1. Size
2. Color

Color image is moving and appearing at the front, once i am selecting the size also.

**But my requirement is:**

image for reference:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PGKh.png

Once someone hit at color button, then same color product should be appear in front of users and after that they can select the size for purchasing.

If i removing the size variation and using the color only then product of same color is appearing but size selection is not appearing...

It would be highly appreciated if someone answer me regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: Your product type must be a variable. and enter the variations data proper for each case.
Please check this reference.
https://woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

Comment: Thats how woocommerce works. Imagine if you want different image for yellow S yellow M and yellow L and so on. You have to complete the variation so woocommerce can pull the proper data. You can modify how its working but that is realy case to case situation.